# regex string capturing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am new to regex in javascript. I have a string something like below:

> "**and** something here ( something else here **and** (something here and something here) something else **or** something else) asdf (**or** asdfas) **and** something here **or** something here ( something else here **and** something else **or** something else)"

From the above string, I am trying to capture group of text based on the following rules:

- Capture a line which starts with `"and"` or `"or"` and ends with `"or"` or `"and"`
- A captured line can have many parenthesis.
- If the operators `"or"` or `"and"` are in parenthesis, then ignore them

From the above string, I am expecting group of result as shown below

> - **and** something here ( something else here **and** (something here and something here) something else **or** something else) asdf (**or** asdfas)
> - and something here
> - or something here ( something else here and something else or something else)

I have tried many regexes and the one which is close to what I want is:

```
(and|or)\s.((?!(and|or)).)*
```

I am ok with a non-regex solution too.

Comment: When you write brackets do you mean parenthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e8tMb/

(If you're interested in an example that supports *nested parenthesis* I added one on the bottom of this answer)

This implementation is *not* pure RegEx, however, it is very understandable in my opinion. It loops through the string and does exactly what you specified in a very simple manner.

Let's say we have our string:

```
var str="and something here ( something else here and something else or something else) and something here or something here ( something else here and something else or something else)";
```

We can [tokeninize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization) it based on relevant punctuation:

```
var tokens = str.split(/( |\(|\))/g)
```

Which results in:

```
["and", " ", "something", " ", "here", " ", "", "(", "", " ", "something", " ", "else", " ", "here", " ", "and", " ", "something", " ", "else", " ", "or", " ", "something", " ", "else", ")", "", " ", "and", " ", "something", " ", "here", " ", "or", " ", "something", " ", "here", " ", "", "(", "", " ", "something", " ", "else", " ", "here", " ", "and", " ", "something", " ", "else", " ", "or", " ", "something", " ", "else", ")", ""]
```

Now, we can iterate these tokens and simply check for sentences:
var str="and something here ( something else here and something else or something else) and something here or something here ( something else here and something else or something else)";

```
var tokens = str.split(/( |\(|\))/g);

var inParans = false;
var sentences = [];
var lastIndex = 0;
for(var i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
    if(tokens[i] === "("){
        inParans = true;
    } else
    if(tokens[i] === ")"){
        inParans = false;
    } else
    if((tokens[i] === "and" || tokens[i] === "or") && !inParans){
        sentences.push(tokens.slice(lastIndex,i).join("")); // add sentence
        lastIndex = i;
    }
}
sentences.push(tokens.slice(lastIndex).join(""));

document.body.innerHTML = (sentences.join("<br />"));
```

#### In case you want to match nested parans

#### Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UbeS8/

With regular expressions in their sense in CS theory it is *impossible* to match nested datacorrectly due to [the pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) (They don't have memory). However, using our tokenizer since we didn't restrict ourselves to a RegExp to begin with, adding this sort of thing is easy, we just count the parenthesis. Unlike Regular Expressions which (in the strict sense don't have memory), we can keep track easily with a variable. Here is such code:

```
var tokens = str.split(/( |\(|\))/g);

var inParans = 0;
var sentences = [];
var lastIndex = 0;
for(var i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
    if(tokens[i] === "("){
        inParans++;
    } else
    if(tokens[i] === ")"){
        inParans--;
        if(inParans < 0){ //invalid syntax
            throw new Error("Invalid syntax");
        }
        //If you don't want this to be an error, you can do what Scott suggested and do
        //            inParans = Math.max(inParans - 1, 0);
    } else
    if((tokens[i] === "and" || tokens[i] === "or") && (inParans===0)){ // no nesting added check
        sentences.push(tokens.slice(lastIndex,i).join("")); // add sentence
        lastIndex = i;
    }
}
sentences.push(tokens.slice(lastIndex).join(""));

document.body.innerHTML = (sentences.join("<br />"));
```

Comment: This fails if nested parentheses are allowed.  Try this string: `"and something here ( something else here and something else (with more and more) or something else) and something here or something here ( something else here and something else or something else)"`

Comment: @ScottSauyet: if nested parentheses are allowed, the only possible solution is recursive descent. OP hasn't said so - so why do you go on like a broken record on every answer about nesting?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: Well, I did so only twice, regarding two very different solutions.  But OP did weigh in (in a comment to [sp00m's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16359408/1243641)) with a second sample that didn't seem particularly well-formed, if I'm reading correctly, but did include the text '`OR default)")) AND `', which strongly suggests to me that nested parentheses might be required.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: OP said "anything in brackets is to be excluded". Doesn't matter how many levels of brackets stuff is in? If it does, OP needs to specify exactly what rules he'd like to apply.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: I suppose so, although I find it pretty simple to infer that if there are brackets it should be excluded, even if they happen to include other nested brackets.  But the devil, as always, is in the details.

Comment: @ScottSauyet This doesn't work for nested parentheses because OP didn't ask for it. However, unlike a RegExp solution this can be easily added to this solution. Instead of setting `inParans` to `true` or `false` you add 1 to it on `"("` and subtract one on `")"`. You only match 'and' or 'or' if inParans is 0. If _you_ are interested to see how this works I don't mind gladly adding such a solution to the answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yes, I was going to suggest that, when my simple attempt to do that broke.  I'm assuming I just did something stupid.  But that **should** work.  I think it would be great to update the answer with that as well.  (And don't forget to not let the count go below zero.)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Okay, I did get it to work.  For some reason, it didn't notice that I meant `parenDepth` when I typed `parentDepth`.  :)

Comment: @ScottSauyet I've updated the answer, I agree that it's an interesting case :) If this _is_ what Mr_Green initially intended indeed than regular expressions are probably the _wrong_ tool in JavaScript (and probably in general).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Very nice!  I suggested an edit, but don't have the authority to edit myself quite yet, which is to replace `inParans--` with `inParans = Math.max(inParans - 1, 0);` so that if the string contains early '`)`' characters they won't mess things up.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I have approved your edit with minor changes :) I initially added the `throw` to the wrong clause (the one that doesn't check nesting). Thanks

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Very nice.  Definitely not a good candidate for Regex, unless the OP really did want a much simplified case.  Thanks for an interesting discussion.

Answer (score 2):

This one should suit your needs ([demo](http://regexr.com?34olv)):

```
\b(?:and|or)\b((?:[(][^)]+[)]|.)+?)(?=\b(?:and|or)\b|$)
```

The data between the ands/ors gets captured in the first group.

Comment: It should match only `or` or `and` but not the words which include them. Like "more", "form", "andy"...

Comment: OP, you said _capture a line_ and actually shown desired result. Please be more specific in formulating your question and the success criteria.

Comment: @Mr_Green how can you accept such an answer? This regex is completely unmaintainable. The very first day you'll have to change something, you'll be completely stuck and will redo it all over.

Comment: It is working somewhat different.. please have a look at this string `t0.ads = "default"
AND sdfasdfa('sdf_asdf') search "(asdfasd OR asdf  +asdfd OR asdf &asdf OR default)")) 
AND  asdf(t0.asdf, t0.asdf, "RTAM", t0.sadf, t0.rs,t0.sadf) = 0 AND  msadfdsa  asdf asd fasf (t0.asdf,t0.asdf,t0.rs,t0.saf,t0.sadf) AS asdf!= ""
AND asdfsdaf_('asdf_afssad') AS hlink != ""`

Comment: @Mr_Green It is just a case problem, try with the CASE_INSENSITIVE flag (i.e. in JS: `/theRegex/i`).

Comment: I am unaccepting your answer to let others to give answers. Sorry for that while. :)

Comment: no, it is not case sensitivity problem. Please check my edited post. I forgot to mention the main thing in it.

Comment: @Mr_Green [It seems to](http://regexr.com?34om8) though. What is the output you expected?

Comment: If nested parentheses are acceptable (and I wouldn't be surprised), then no regex solution will work.  See for example: http://regexr.com?34ome